# Смена текста с помощью CSS3 анимации (как новости на главной Яндекса))

Tags: css3, css-animation

Доброго времени суток!

Сейчас код такой:

```css
h1 {
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner at 50% 50%, #f6f78f, #f2d03c) repeat 0 0 #f6f78f;
  border-top: 1px dotted #537098;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #537098;
  padding: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32pt !important;
}
```

```html
<h1>Заголовок</h1>
```

Нужно, чтобы, например, раз в 2 секунды «Заголовок» `slideUp` за секунду и выезжал с низа строки «Заголовок-2», потом через 2 сек. «Заголовок-2» `slideUp` за сек. и выезжал с низа строки «Заголовок-3». Анимация должна быть зациклена. Фраз внутри `H1` может быть 2+. Понимаю, что это всё делается как-то с помощью `@keyframes`, `animation`, но не получилось разобраться. Прошу накидать код!  Буду благодарен! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Пришлось зайти на Yandex и посмотреть о чём речь ... о Ротаторе новостей речь

Или воспользуйтесь [этим плагинчиком](http://pcvector.net/demo.html?link=/uploads/demo/scripts/text_and_link_effects/atrotating/index.html) ..самый верхний пример как раз ваш вариант

```css
*{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
ul{
  margin:50px 0;
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:16px;
  padding:0 0 0 10px;

}
ul li{
  margin:1px 0;
  height:16px;
}
ul li a{
  font-size:14px;
}
ul div{
  animation:tween 28s ease infinite ;
}

@keyframes tween{
  0%{
    margin-top:0;
  }
  40%{
    margin-top:-20px;
  }
  60%{
    margin-top:-40px;
  }
  80%{
    margin-top:-60px;
  }
  100%{
    margin-top:0;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <div>
    <li>новость первая</li>
    <li>вторая новость</li>
    <li>ещё что то выводится</li>
    <li>опять какая то новость</li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: Никогда бы не догадался. А такое решение кроссбраузерное?

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev  я смотрел в трех браузерах и работало :))